# Should we flag off-topic answers to questions when they were previously on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, old-questions, late-answers

When I'm bored I sometimes go to the review queues to help out.
A few times in the *Late Answers* review queue I've got questions and answers like this:

[image]

The [specific review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6205347) is located here, but I have not taken any action on it (I skipped it) as I'm a little confused on whether it is off-topic.
The answer is off-topic by *today's Stack Overflow rules*, but however is *on-topic* if we go by *the rules of Stack Overflow at the time this question was posted*.
The answer to this is probably going to be *flag it as off-topic*, and this now leaves the actual question.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757594/what-is-the-best-choice-for-a-corporate-wiki-blog-software-tool) was posted back in 2009 when Stack Overflow was more relaxed about these kind of questions, but now they're off-topic.

What is the best action to take when stumbling across one of these prior-off-topic questions?
I can see three likely answers to this:

- Leave them
- Downvote/flag as off-topic
- Request migration to [the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

How should we handle these?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Questions** are on or off-topic. Answers are either addressing the question, or not an answer. Treat them as such, regardless of wether or not they'd have been tolerated in the past.

If the answer is posted to a question that is now off-topic, visit the question and vote to close it. I've voted to close the [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757594/what-is-the-best-choice-for-a-corporate-wiki-blog-software-tool) for your example, as it is off-topic now. Always judge questions by today's rules, we don't need broken windows around here.

Note that migration is not an option here; only [*recent*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) and high-quality questions should be migrated. This question fails to meet both standards, nor is it even on-topic for Software Recommendations (it is not nearly specific enough).

Whatever you do, do *not* flag an *answer* if it is the question that is problematic. Moderators have better things to do than handle question closures that can be better farmed out to the community instead.

Comment: Yes, this please. Moderators would much rather deal with the root cause of a problem, rather than treat the symptoms. It's easy for us to miss an off-topic question when people only flag the answers.